# What is the "select" tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is ambiguous (in my opinion) tag [select](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/select) which has over 60 posts, but it's not clear what it is used for.

Is it SELECT for MySQL, select list, select modules (such as HS, SHS, TSS) or anything else?

Answer (score 2):

It is used for everything you listed, and maybe more. It should be removed, or replaced from existing tags because, as it is used now, it is not helpful at all.